# I'm trying to curl X Post in terminal but my file is too large

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, curl

I'm trying to import a file to elasticsearch (it's a container). I'm using a CURL -X Post to do this but I receiving a message saying "Request Entity Too Large"

My file has 1.1GB and I tried to change the nginx.conf including "client_max_body_size 100M" and I entered the elasticsearch container to change elasticsearch.yml and put "http.max_length...=2GB" but it 
idn't work

This is my curl

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" http://localhost:9200/data/1 -T inventory
```

This is my return.

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
content-length: 0
```

I expect that my endpoint "http://localhost:9200/data/1" load the inventory_ file data

Comment: `client_max_body_size 9G`

Comment: I got it but I didn't use the curl. I used 'elasticdump'.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum request size for Elasticsearch by default is 100MB (uncompressed) — once you've configured nginx to pass through such large requests. You can change it through [`http.max_content_length`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html).

But this soft limit is there for a reason. Is there no way to split the requests into smaller chunks? Bigger requests are not (necessarily) more efficient and you'll really push the heap with such big requests.